# error when using pointers, dynamically allocating ,struct

Tags: c, struct, declaration, member-access

My code don't run ,how can I fix it
i think i don't understand where i am wrong
error when using pointers, dynamically allocating ,struct

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"
struct nhanVien{
    int code;
    char name[50];
    char sex[50];
    int numb;
    int wage;
};
void input(nhanVien *worker,int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Nhap ma nhanVien : ");
        scanf("%d",(worker->code+i));
        
    }
}
int main(){
    nhanVien *worker;
    int n;
    printf("Nhap so luong nhan vien : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    worker = (nhanVien*)malloc(n*sizeof(nhanVien));
    input(worker,n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Nhap ma nhanVien : %d \n",*(worker->code+i));
        
    }
    free(worker);
    
}
```

Invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int') Error in C
this is images [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Bt0.png)

Comment: `scanf("%d",(worker->code+i));` - what this line is supposed to do? `worker->code+i` is an integer, while `scanf` is expecting a pointer.

Comment: It looks like `worker->code+i` should be `worker[i].code`.

Comment: @mch `&worker[i].code`

Comment: @EugeneSh. for the `scanf`, but not the `printf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a number of issues in your code, `worker->code+i` should be `worker[i].code`; you're missing `typedef` on the `struct` type. Basically, you want something like

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"

typedef struct {
    int code;
    char name[50];
    char sex[50];
    int numb;
    int wage;
} nhanVien;

void input(nhanVien *worker,int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Nhap ma nhanVien : ");
        scanf("%d", &worker[i].code);
    }
}

int main() {
    nhanVien *worker;
    int n;
    printf("Nhap so luong nhan vien : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    worker = (nhanVien*)malloc(n*sizeof(nhanVien));
    input(worker,n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Nhap ma nhanVien : %d \n",worker[i].code);
    }
    free(worker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name `nhanVien` is not declared. There is declared the type specifier `struct nhanVien`.

So you need use this name as for example

```
void input( struct nhanVien *worker,int n){
```

or

```
struct nhanVien *worker;
```

or

```
worker = (struct nhanVien*)malloc(n*sizeof( struct nhanVien));
```

This call of scanf

```
scanf("%d",(worker->code+i));
```

is incorrect. You need to write either

```
scanf("%d", &( worker + i )->code);
```

or

```
scanf("%d", &worker[i].code);
```

Also this call of printf

```
printf("Nhap ma nhanVien : %d \n",*(worker->code+i));
```

is incorrect. You need to write

```
printf("Nhap ma nhanVien : %d \n", worker[i].code);
```